# How do I enable curl for php

Tags: php, curl, nginx, debian

I'm using NGINX with PHP-FPM on Debian Wheezy via DotDeb repo.

This is the only curl reference in my php.ini file and I'm not sure what I need to do. Any help is appreciated (it's already installed)

```
[curl]
; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This is required to be an
; absolute path.
;curl.cainfo =

; Local Variables:
; tab-width: 4
; End:
```

Comment: I believe you have to add (or uncomment) line in your php.ini: `extension=php_curl.so` and then restart php-fpm.

Comment: I tried this but it said Unable to load module ---- no such file or directory

Answer (score 12):

Check whether you have `php5-curl` installed

```
dpkg -l | grep 'php5-curl'
```

If isn't installed,

```
apt-get install php5-curl
```

Ensure the path in `extension_dir` exists, and contains curl.so, if not, change to the correct path.

```
php -i | grep extension_dir
```

Ensure the `/etc/php5/mods-available/curl.ini` exists and has the curl.so loaded

```
; configuration for php CURL module
; priority=20
extension=curl.so
```

If everything is correct, restart PHP-FPM

```
/etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart
```

Comment: Hi, curl is already installed (as mentioned in the question) -- I just don't know how to enable it in php.ini.

Comment: Go to phpinfo, check whether the path listed in `extension_dir` exists or not. And in `/etc/php5/mods-available/curl.ini`, it should be `extension=curl.so`, or the *curl.so that you find in `extension_dir`.

Answer (score -2):

To enable curl on Windows uncomment

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
;to
extension=php_curl.dll
```