# Composer install missing curl-ext

Tags: composer-php, php-curl

I am developing some PHP on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LS. Running `composer install` is failing and I can't figure it out.  This was working earlier when I was using PHP 5.5.9, but I had to update to at least 5.6 in order to install phpunit.

Running `php -v` outputs:

```
PHP 5.6.23-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+2 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

Running `which php` outputs:

```
/usr/bin/php
```

which is kind of suspicious as it doesn't match `php -v` (/usr/bin has: "php", "php5", and "php5.6")

Here is my composer.json:

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "5.4.*"
    },
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "~1.3",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "3.*"
    }
}
```

Running `composer install` creates this output:

```
$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
- stripe/stripe-php v3.9.2 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.9.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.9.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.8.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.7.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.7.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.6.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.5.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.4.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.3.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.2.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.14.3 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.14.2 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.14.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.14.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.13.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.12.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.12.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.11.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.10.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.10.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.1.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.0.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.14.2 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- Installation request for stripe/stripe-php 3.* -> satisfiable by stripe/stripe-php[v3.0.0, v3.1.0, v3.10.0, v3.10.1, v3.11.0, v3.12.0, v3.12.1, v3.13.0, v3.14.0, v3.14.1, v3.14.2, v3.14.3, v3.2.0, v3.3.0, v3.4.0, v3.5.0, v3.6.0, v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.8.0, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

I followed these instructions but it doesnt work: [Composer install error - requires ext_curl when it's actually enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335305/composer-install-error-requires-ext-curl-when-its-actualy-enabled)

Running `php -i | grep php.ini` outputs:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/5.6/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini
```

Running: `sudo apt-get install php5-curl` outputs:

```
php5-curl is already the newest version.
```

Running `curl -V` outputs:

```
curl 7.35.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.35.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Typing ``dpkg -l | grep 'php5-curl'`` outputs:


``ii  php5-curl                                             5.6.23+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 amd64        CURL module for php5``

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some notes:

- Running `php -i` is good. It shows you the `php.ini` used, so that you know which file to edit.
- Running `curl -v` is not needed, because that's the standalone curl for usage on the CLI and unrelated to the PHP Extension curl.
- You checked for `php5-curl`, that's the needed package. Ok.

What's missing? You need to make sure the extension is also loaded by PHP!

Edit your `/etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini`, search for `extension`, look for `php_curl` and enable it: `extension=php_curl.so`.

Then run `php -m` on the CLI to see the list of loaded modules and ensure that curl is loaded.

Finally, re-run your `composer install`.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The php.ini file does not have a php_curl.so -- it has php_curl.dll, but that's for windows and I'm on Ubuntu.  Enabling this line did not work.  The file only has two .so mentions, both for mysql.

I got the "extensions_dir" from phpinfo(), and there is a "curl.so" in that directory.

I followed the instructions from here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233460/how-do-i-enable-curl-for-php  and the file /etc/php5/mods-available/curl.ini does exist, and it does have "extension=curl.so" in it.

Updating question above.

Comment: Right, when on Linux/Ubuntu you need to enable the `.so` file. I wonder why enabling that didn't work, when you already found the `php_curl.so` file in the extension folder. Please check with `php -m`, if it is loaded. -- If it is not loaded, i think you are still editing the wrong `php.ini` for the PHP you are using on the CLI. Keep in mind that there a differnt php.ini files - for web requests and for the CLI.

Comment: ``php -m`` does not list curl.

The command ``php -i | grep php.ini`` makes me think I am editing the proper php.ini file.

In that php.ini file I added ``extension=/path/to/extensions/curl.so`` (got the path from the output of ``phpinfo()``) and now ``php -m`` lists curl.  Now when I run ``composer install`` I am getting an error about another missing package (ext-mbstring), so that seems to work.

Comment: But the fact that I keep getting errors makes me think something is wrong.  

Typing ``dpkg -l | grep 'php5-curl'`` outputs: ``ii php5-curl 5.6.23+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 amd64 CURL module for php5``.  Notice it has "deprecated+dontuse" in there.

When upgrading my PHP version, it did not go smoothly, I saw this "deprecated" message and did another upgrade to a higher version.  Perhaps I will uninstall all PHP and start again.

Comment: Glad it worked out. | Well, if the curl extension is properly loaded and you don't get an API conflict between PHP extension and PHP core displayed, when you run PHP, then it simply works - even if it is flagged as deprecated. | If you get an API mismatch, then reinstalling PHP with extensions might clear the situation.

Answer (score 24):

Execute this:
`sudo apt-get install php-curl`

Answer (score 0):

if ubuntu is not a server edition, and the webserver was installed with `tasksel`
try installing php
`apt-get install php`