# Cannot Update Composer in Command Line

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am updating the composer and it shows up some error like below.

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
Problem 1
    - pusher/pusher-php-server v3.4.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - pusher/pusher-php-server v3.4.0 requires php >=5.4 <7.3 -> your PHP version (7.3.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - pusher/pusher-php-server v3.3.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - pusher/pusher-php-server v3.3.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - pusher/pusher-php-server 3.4.x-dev requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for pusher/pusher-php-server ^3.3 -> satisfiable by pusher/pusher-php-server[3.4.x-dev, v3.3.0, v3.3.1, v3.4.0, v3.4.1].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\PHP7\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Comment: Which php version is installed in your system ? and which OS ?

Comment: Did you check this post ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/22618953/5928015

Comment: and did you write this in your composer `php >=5.4 <7.3` ?? if you did please remove it put something like this `"php": "^7.1.3",`

Comment: My php ver: 7.3.6 and i'm using window... and i didn't make any change in composer file.

Comment: Well, have you even read that error message? If you added the constraint for `php < 7.3` in that file, and run composer using PHP 7.3.6, the problem is pretty obvious

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composer install missing curl-ext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024937/composer-install-missing-curl-ext)

Answer (score 3):

the pusher v3 doesn't support php version that higher than 7.3

there are some options :

first is downgrade the php to the requirement (not recomended), the second one is  use this command to upgrade the pusher to version 4

```
composer require pusher/pusher-php-server
```

Answer (score -2):

could please check curl enabled in your php use ;extension=php_curl.dll  remove semi colon in php.ini file and try [image: if curl enabled]

Comment: Please explain why one should check that and how checking that would resolve the given problems

Comment: may be your composer.json contains some package which use curl  you can check whether the curl is enabled or not using simple create a php file and test if its in local machine  <?php echo phpinfo(); ?>  and  if need more assistance in enabling the curl use the following link  http://www.tomjepson.co.uk/enabling-curl-in-php-php-ini-wamp-xamp-ubuntu/

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the answer, not to the comment section. Additionally, you have not explained why checking for that cURL extension helps to resolve all of the error messages.

Answer (score -3):

try following command

install first curl using following command.

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

then use

```
sudo apt-get install composer
```

Comment: Please explain **why** one should try that. Using the given message, I see no need to install `composer` once more