# How to enable curl in nginx

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, nginx

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, PHP 5.5.9 and Nginx.

I already installed the newest `php5-curl` version and add `"extension=php_curl.dll"` into `"/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini"`
I also restart service `php5-fpm` and `nginx`.

But when I run the code (*run at localhost on windows 10, it is still working*) I received the following message:

> **Fatal error:** Call to undefined function curl_init() in
>   /usr/share/nginx ...

Help fix it!
Thank you!

Comment: [have you seen this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23233611/1572077)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you really enabled the module for `php-fpm` and not PHP CLI by opening page with just [phpinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php):

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Then look for enabled modules or for `./configure` command arguments which might include `curl` when building the source code of PHP.

Comment: Hi, Martin! I only saw a table "Module Authors" which the first column is cURl and the second column is Sterling Hughes. I don't find any world "cURL" else. I don't know what to continue.

Comment: Well, if you can't see it anywhere it's not loaded. Are you sure you're using the correct `.ini` file? At the top you should see all `.ini` files loaded as `Loaded Configuration File` and `Additional .ini files parsed`. Btw, are you sure it doesn't throw any error on startup because it can't find your extension?

Comment: I sure i'm using the correct .ini file because I changed max execution time limit and it could run correctly.