# My server block in Nginx can't load my PHP

Tags: nginx, server, block, ioncube

I hope you're having a wonderful time. I have been fighting for the last 14 days trying to set up my VPS from digital ocean with all the basic elements including Apache2 afterI discovered that Apache2 is less complicated and faster, I installed Nginx instead. I installed all the necessary elements such as LEMP and Phpmyadmin etc.

The problem I'm facing here is that I seem to be stuck in making a PHP file work in one of my 2 server blocks ( I have one (example.com) with the as the default server and another (test.com) without). The php file from CPVlab ( a tracking tool) is called check-server-requirements.php. a script that checks if the server is ready to get CPVlab installed on it.

When I upload the php file to /var/www/example.com or test.com/html and try to access it via ((example.com)(test.com)/check-server-requirements.php) it shows me a blank page.

Knowing that that script is encoded by ioncube. Therefore it needs ioncube installed on my server in order to run. I did that as well and according to the loader script of ioncube it's successfully installed.

Below you'll find each of my serverblocks configs:

for example.com:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /var/www/example.com/html;
index index.html index.htm;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name example.com www.example.com;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
}

location /phpmyadmin {
        auth_basic "Admin Login";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pma_pass;
}

# Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
#location /RequestDenied {
#   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    
#}

error_page 404 /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
#   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
#
#   # With php5-cgi alone:
#   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#   # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

For test.com:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

root /var/www/test.com/html;
index index.php index.htm;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name test.com www.test.com;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
}

location /phpmyadmin {
        auth_basic "Admin Login";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pma_pass;
}

# Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
#location /RequestDenied {
#   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    
#}

error_page 404 /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
#   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
#
#   # With php5-cgi alone:
#   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#   # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
#   deny all;
#}
```

}

This is the error I find in error.log when I try to access the script through the domains:

```
2017/07/17 20:54:56 [error] 1180#0: *78 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER - assumed 'CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER' in /var/www/test.com/html/check-server-requirements.php on line 0
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_HEADER - assumed 'CURLOPT_HEADER' in /var/www/test.com/html/check-server-requirements.php on line 0

PHP message: PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_ENCODING - assumed 'CURLOPT_ENCODING' in /var/www/test.com/html/check-server-requirements.php on line 0

PHP message: PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT - assumed 'CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT' in /var/www/test.com/html/check-server-requirements.php on line 0

PHP message: PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_TIMEOUT - assumed 'CURLOPT_TIMEOUT' in /var/www/test.com/html/check-server-requirements.php on line 0

PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init() in /var/www/test.com/html/check-server-requirements.php on line 0" while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xx.250, server: test.com, request: "GET /check-server-requirements.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "test.com"
```

I would really appreciate some help for this issue. Thank you in advance.

P.S: the server blocks (domains) are successfully working.

Comment: Try this: You don't have cURL installed.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/curl-is-not-installed-in-your-php-installation

Comment: I was about to point the same, related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233460/how-do-i-enable-curl-for-php